# Textblock Run Printing

Tags: silverlight, textblock, printdocument

It appears that if you have a Textblock with a Run in it that it will not print with a PrintDocument in Silverlight 5. Anyone else have this problem or a solution?

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Left"
                           FontFamily="Arial"
                           FontSize="14">
                    <Run Text="{Binding type}"/>
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding size}"/>
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding grade}"/>
                </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the same issue.  Unfortunately I have not found a solution.  My work-around is to rewrite the TextBlock as a series of TextBlocks contained inside a StackPanel with Orientation set to Horizontal.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. 
To critique or request clarification from an author, 
leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, 
and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.